# Stuck in multiple ajax requests

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been bulding scheduler using jquery and ajax. I am stuck with multiple ajax request problem. The logic is correct and it returns correct value most of the time, but sometime once or twice in more than 50 requests, I find error values.

I have grabbed the post values in php send my jquery. lets say, i have grabbed device_id from jquery in server side. But sometimes, i get device_id[], which results in database error in server side, throwing error then in ajax requests. I am uploading the image of my error in firebug debugging area.

Success request
[image]

Error Request

[image]

My ajax request EventDrop Code

```
eventDrop: function( event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {

                    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

                    (
                        function (t1,t2,t3,t4)
                        {
                            if(update_allocation(t1, t2, t3, t4)==true)
                            {
                                alert('true');
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //revertFunc();
                                alert('false');
                            }
                        }(event.allocation_id,event.resource,start,end)
                    )
```

My update allocation function

```
<script>

    function update_allocation(allocationid,device,start,end)
    {

        var b_val=0;
        var postData_updatecart = {
                    'allocation_id' : allocationid,
                    'device_id': device,
                    'start': start,
                    'end': end

                };

        $.ajax({

                    url : base_url + 'admin/allocations/update_allocation',
                    type : 'post',
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,

                    data: postData_updatecart,

                    beforeSend : function() {
                        $('#result_container').html('Updating...');

                    },

                    success : function(myval) {


                        $('#result_container').html(myval);




                    }
                }); 

            if(b_val==1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }


    }


</script>








            //alert('event moved to '+event.allocation_id+' to '+event.resource);

        },
```

Response in failed request

```
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Array to string conversion</p>
<p>Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 453</p>

</div><html>
<head>
<title>Database Error</title>
<style type="text/css">

body {
background-color:   #fff;
margin:             40px;
font-family:        Lucida Grande, Verdana, Sans-serif;
font-size:          12px;
color:              #000;
}

#content  {
border:             #999 1px solid;
background-color:   #fff;
padding:            20px 20px 12px 20px;
}

h1 {
font-weight:        normal;
font-size:          14px;
color:              #990000;
margin:             0 0 4px 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
        <p>Error Number: 1054</p><p>Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'</p><p>SELECT *
FROM (`wiyo_devices`)
WHERE `device_id` = Array</p>   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Failing ajax request now at 5th call

[image]

Comment: In the console, what's in the `response` tab of a failed request?

Comment: i've added response in my question (At last). I have edited my question.

Comment: The answer is in your response @atomaprchya

Comment: But initially it is correct, sometimes at 4th time, sometime at 5th, sometime at 2nd it is throwing error. Most of time, the ajax call is not making problem. What should i do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In failed request your device id is an javascript array.

`device_id[]=4`

Check your javascript code to remove array from `device_id`

or handle it server side.

To handle it server side you can use code below:

```
$device_id=$_POST['device_id'];
if(is_array($device_id)){
 $device_id=array_shift($device_id);
}
```

in you query use `$device_id` variable.

Or you can use implode function.

Comment: I used the given code, and my problem is solved. But, what was the main problem. How your code solved it??

Comment: in you failed request your javascript was sending array as `device_id`. my code was checking if device_id is array then get first element value (array_shift: http://in3.php.net/array_shift)

Answer (score -1):

Issue is here

```
        if(update_allocation(t1, t2, t3, t4)==true)
                        {
                            alert('true');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //revertFunc();
                            alert('false');
                        }
```

as update_allocation is supposed to make async calls,  and your if block does not wait for the async call. It thinks the function call will return data immediately.

Let's do one thing, write your alert() call in update_allocation() method in success callback method.

Comment: I think it doesnt make a sense. I need value from my function to be checked. ALert are just only checking tools.

Comment: @atomaprchya man! execution of eventDrop is linear whereas update_allocation will return you result after the async call is over. It's not because you want, technically your code is correct or not that you need to see.